# How can I use something like NativeList<NativeList<Vector3Int>>? or any other alternative ways?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jobs, primitive

I am trying to calculate normals of a mesh manually using the job system for better performance. In my solution I am trying to use something like NativeList>. But when I compiled I got an error says that:

ArgumentException: Unity.Collections.NativeList`1[UnityEngine.Vector3Int] used in native collection is not blittable or primitive

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Thank you guys!

```
public class NormalCalculatorJobSystem
{
List<List<Vector3Int>> verticesAdjFaces;
List<Vector3> normals;
Mesh mesh = null;

NativeArray<int> nativeIndices;
NativeList<NativeList<Vector3Int>> nativeVerticesAdjFaces;
NativeList<Vector3> nativeNormals;
NativeArray<Vector3> nativeVertices;

InitAdjacentFacesJob initAdjacentFacesJob;
JobHandle initAdjacentFacesJobHandle;

CalculateNormalsJob calculateNormalsJob;
JobHandle calculateNormalsJobHandle;

public void Init(Mesh _mesh)
{
    mesh = _mesh;
    verticesAdjFaces = new List<List<Vector3Int>>();


    nativeIndices = new NativeArray<int>(mesh.triangles, Allocator.Temp);

    //ArgumentException: Unity.Collections.NativeList`1[UnityEngine.Vector3Int] used in native collection is not blittable or primitive
    nativeVerticesAdjFaces = new NativeList<NativeList<Vector3Int>>(mesh.vertexCount,Allocator.Temp);


    nativeNormals = new NativeList<Vector3>(mesh.normals.Length, Allocator.Temp);
    nativeVertices = new NativeArray<Vector3>(mesh.vertices, Allocator.Temp);

    InitAdjacentFaces();
}

public void InitAdjacentFaces() {

    initAdjacentFacesJob = new InitAdjacentFacesJob
    {
        indices = nativeIndices,
        verticesAdjFaces = nativeVerticesAdjFaces,
    };

    initAdjacentFacesJobHandle = initAdjacentFacesJob.Schedule(mesh.vertexCount, 64);
    initAdjacentFacesJobHandle.Complete();
}

public struct InitAdjacentFacesJob : IJobParallelFor
{
    public NativeArray<int> indices;
    public NativeList<NativeList<Vector3Int>> verticesAdjFaces;
    public void Execute(int i)
    {
        NativeList<Vector3Int> list = new NativeList<Vector3Int>();
        for (int j = 0; j < indices.Length; j += 3)
        {
            if (list.Length > 6)
                continue;
            if (i == indices[j] || i == indices[j + 1] || i == indices[j + 2])
            {
                Vector3Int triangle = new Vector3Int(indices[j], indices[j + 1], indices[j + 2]);
                list.Add(triangle);
            }
        }
        verticesAdjFaces.Add(list);
    }
}


public void CalculateNormals(Mesh mesh)
{
    nativeNormals.Clear();
    calculateNormalsJob = new CalculateNormalsJob
    {
        vertices = nativeVertices,
        verticesAdjFaces = nativeVerticesAdjFaces,
        normals = nativeNormals
    };
    calculateNormalsJobHandle = calculateNormalsJob.Schedule(nativeVerticesAdjFaces.Length, 64,initAdjacentFacesJobHandle);
    calculateNormalsJobHandle.Complete();
    normals = new List<Vector3>(nativeNormals.ToArray());
    mesh.SetNormals(normals);
}

public struct CalculateNormalsJob : IJobParallelFor {
    public NativeArray<Vector3> vertices;
    public NativeList<NativeList<Vector3Int>> verticesAdjFaces;
    public NativeList<Vector3> normals;
    public void Execute(int i)
    {
        NativeList<Vector3Int> adjFaces = verticesAdjFaces[i];
        Vector3 normal = Vector3.zero;
        for (int j = 0; j < adjFaces.Length; j++)
        {
            Vector3Int triangle = adjFaces[j];
            Vector3 vec0 = vertices[triangle.y] - vertices[triangle.x];
            Vector3 vec1 = vertices[triangle.z] - vertices[triangle.x];
            normal += Vector3.Cross(vec0, vec1);
        }
        normal.Normalize();
        normals.Add(normal);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A blittable type is a type which has a canonical representation in both managed and unmanaged code. You can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types).

For DOTS, Unity have invented their own blittable value types, which are more similar to what you'd see in a shading language like HLSL. For vectors, you have float2, float3, float4, etc. You also have float4x4 for matrices. In your case, you want int3 rather than Vector3Int. One benefit of using these new types is that they can leverage SIMD operations (Single Instruction, Multiple Data) which allows arithmetic operations to be used on all 3 values in a single instruction.

These new types also have their own intrinsic operations for things like cross and dot products. You can find the Mathematics library on [GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity.Mathematics/blob/master/src/Unity.Mathematics/math.cs).